# Scan a document, find a line, extract numbers below

Tags: simulink

I have the following .csv file:

```
Marker,"loop_-105"
Id,1

"Time (Seconds)","Sig (ts)"
"1.920576","3.98"
"1.957907","31.58"
"1.9912","34.422"
...

Marker,"loop_-102.1"
Id,1

"Time (Seconds)","Sig (ts)"
"4.920576","3.98"
"2.07","31.58"
"1.9912","34.422"
...
```

I want to open the file, extract the values -105 and -102.1 along with the values in quotes in two matrices. I have tried textscan and regex but did not quite work.

```
str2double(regexp(filetext, '(?<=loop_[^0-9]*)[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+', 'match'));

find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(new_measurement,'Time (Seconds)","Sig (ts)')))
```

Comment: "it did not quite work" is ambiguous. You may have made a typo, you may have written it wrong, it may not be the right way of doing it or it may have short-circuited your laptop, as far as we know. Can you show what you tried so we can help you with that?

Comment: @AnderBiguri right, please check the edited question.

Comment: Can you just `strfind` `loop_` and then just take all the characters after until a newline appears?

Comment: @AnderBiguri problem is I do not know how many lines are there each time.

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected output is?

Comment: Try `regexp(filetext, 'loop_\D*?(\d*\.?\d+)', 'tokens','noemptymatch')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one attempt, I hope I understood correctly what you'd like to achieve.

I used the following file `data.csv`

```
Marker,"loop_-105"
Id,1

"Time (Seconds)","Sig (ts)"
"1.920576","3.98"
"1.957907","31.58"
"1.9912","34.422"
"1.920576","3.98"
"1.957907","31.58"
"1.9912","34.422"


Marker,"loop_-102.1"
Id,1

"Time (Seconds)","Sig (ts)"
"4.920576","3.98"
"2.07","31.58"
"1.9912","34.422"
```

and the following script to read it:

```
filename = './data.csv';

% read all lines as strings
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
rawdata = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);

% get the single lines
lines = rawdata{1};

% two regexp, one for the Marker, one for the values
startregexp = 'Marker,"loop_(?<startnum>-{0,1}\d+.{0,1}\d*)"';
valueregexp = '"(?<v1>\d+.{0,1}\d*)","(?<v2>\d+.{0,1}\d*)"';

% Data is stored in this cell
result = {};

% Loop through the lines
for lcount = 1:numel(lines)
    start = regexp(lines{lcount}, startregexp, 'names');
    if ~isempty(start)
        % The Marker-Regexp matched, start a new cell entry
        result{end+1} = struct(...
            'Loop', str2double(start.startnum), ...
            'values', []);
        continue
    end

    values = regexp(lines{lcount}, valueregexp, 'names');
    if ~isempty(values)
        % the value regexp matched. Add data 
        result{end}.values(end+1, :) = [str2double(values.v1) str2double(values.v2)];
    end
end
```

`result` is:

```
>> result

result =

  1×2 cell array

    {1×1 struct}    {1×1 struct}

>> result{1}

ans = 

  struct with fields:

      Loop: -105
    values: [6×2 double]

>> result{1}.values

ans =

    1.9206    3.9800
    1.9579   31.5800
    1.9912   34.4220
    1.9206    3.9800
    1.9579   31.5800
    1.9912   34.4220
```

Comment: I owe you a beer.